# How to overcome version incompatibility with Abaqus and Numpy (Python's library)?

Tags: python, numpy, nlopt, abaqus

I want to run an external library of python called `NLopt` within Abaqus through python. The issue is that the NLopt I found is compiled against the latest release of Numpy, **i.e. 1.9**, whereas Abaqus 6.13-2 is compiled against Numpy 1.4. I tried to replace the Numpy folder under the site-packages under the Abaqus installation folder with the respective one of version 1.9 that I created externally through an installation of Numpy 1.9 over Python 2.6 (version that Abaqus uses).

Abaqus couldn't even start so I guess that such approach is incorrect.

Are there any suggestions on how to overcome such issue?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems. As an (annoying) work around I usually write out important data in text files using the regular python. Afterwards, using a bash script, I start a second python (different version) to further analyse the data (matplotlib etc).